Solo escribir en el input cuando tenga un símbolo por delante
Necesito si es que es posible hacerlo, calculo que con JS lo cual no le conozco como para programar lo que necesito, soy mas de PHP. Tengo un input, el cual va a hacer usado con un lector de código QR, pero el cliente quiere que únicamente marque, cuando tenga un * adelante y luego la numeración. Esto para que nadie pueda escribir desde la table o presione y queden caracteres en el input por error. Luego al enviar los datos por PHP a la BD, en el proceso de envió limpiar y quitar el *
Este es el input
<input autofocus class="input_user" type='text' name="dni" id='dni' value="" placeholder="N° 
 DNI" required/><span id="error"></span>

y tengo este script que me ayudaron desde aca a crearlo, para que se ejecute una vez cargado el input.
             window.addEventListener("load",function(){
                                formulario = document.formulario;
                                dni = document.formulario.dni;
                                campoError = document.getElementById("error");
                                                    
                                dni.addEventListener("input",function(){
                                    campoError.innerHTML= "";
                                });

                                dni.addEventListener("keyup",envioAutomatico);
                            });

                            function enviarFormulario(e){
                                e = e || window.event;
                                    if(dni.value==""){ 
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        campoError.innerHTML ="rellene este campo";
                                    }else{
                                        console.log("se ha procedio al envío del 
           formulario");
                                };
                            };

                            function envioAutomatico(){
                                if ( dni.value.length == 8 ) {
                                    formulario.addEventListener("submit",enviarFormulario);
                                    formulario.submit();
                                }
                            }

Como como investigar o como deberia avanzar si es posible hacerlo?
EDIT:
Estuve probando este codigo
JS:
    var valor = e.value.replace(/^2*/, '');
    e.value = valor;

Donde lo que hago es si se presiona como primera istancia el numero 2 lo quita, y funciona, pero no se como implementar que cualquier tecla que sea primera y no sea el asterisco, lo quite, luego que el asterisco este primero, ahi si se pueda escribir el resto.

Pero eso de Solo escribir cuando..., no se cumpliría si se pone (a mano y no por lector de QR) el asterisco en el input no? En resumen, cual es el problema de escribir el DNI con un * antes?? Porque eso de que nadie pueda escribir desde la Tablet o lo que sea (en un input) lo veo raro. Escriben con un asterisco antes y ya

claro, mas que nada es para que si se presiona alguna tecla sin querer y queda marcada en el input, no se envie y genere un error, quieren evitar eso. Por eso se configuro que en el QR se envie un * primero

la idea es que nadie escriba, solo sea el qr, pero en la manipulacion de la tablet, no quede algo escrito por esa manipulacion.

Voy a estar pendiente de la solución porque aunque sea con QR siempre tendrán que "escribir" en el input, aunque sea por lectura, el input va a recibir un valor, la pregunta es, que lo diferencia de una escritura manual?? Hasta se podría copiar algo como *12345678N y pegarlo en el input, que hará de diferente el QR es lo que me llama la atención. Diferente fuera si de una url con QR se tratara, porque tomarían el valor del DNI que el QR trajera y lo pondrían en un label y eso si no lo podrían modificar pero pueda que o no haya entendido bien o no tenga todo el contexto. Suerte

No se entiende muy bien la solicitud bro, pero he intentado releer varias veces y lo que entiendo es lo siguiente:

Tienes un input
Su valor será llenado al escanear un código QR
Quieren limitarlo para que nadie pueda escribir en el input por accidente

Si las premisas anteriores son correctas, no necesitas una solución tan rebuscada con el asterisco, solamente tienes que evitar que el usuario pueda escribir algo él y ya.
Y para esto, te ofrezco la siguiente solución redundante para mayor seguridad:

En el input vas a colocar el atributo maxlength, y le vas a colocar el valor = 0:
<input autofocus class="input_user" type='text' name="dni" id='dni' value="" placeholder="N° DNI" maxlength="0" required/>


Además, debes de hacer uso del atributo onpaste, y agregarle un "return false" para evitar el copia y pegue:
<input autofocus class="input_user" type='text' name="dni" id='dni' value="" placeholder="N° DNI" maxlength="0" onpaste="return false" required/>


Para mayor tranquilidad, si deseas, puedes agregar el siguiente JS para evitar cualquier intento de input por teclado
let input = document.getElementById('dni');
input.addEventListener('keydown',deny);
input.addEventListener('paste',deny);

function deny(e){
    e.preventDefault()
}



Espero que te sea de utilidad, Saludos

Me salta la mera curiosidad del hecho que si le pone un maxlength="0" como va a recibir o mejor dicho como el input va a manejar los 9 caracteres del DNI??? Puedes iluminarme?? Pueda que no esté viendo algo y por eso mi curiosidad... PD: el Link es la documentación de maxlength

No sé si estás siendo sarcástico bro, pero solo basta con que hagas la prueba, aunque le pongas ese atributo, a través de JS puedes asignarle valores a ese input, que asumo que es así como van a agregar los datos del QR, no va a ser un programa que va a escanear el código y crear una persona mágica que va a teclear el valor del QR cierto? Va a ser un script que va a tomar ese número e insertarlo en el input con JS o incluso, si por ejemplo fuese un form creado con PHP, en El value se le coloca un echo()

Puedes agregarle un eventlistener al input para que cada vez que se pulse una tecla, si el texto no empieza por * borre todo.
dni = document.getElementById("dni");
dni.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=> {
    const tempId = e.target.value;
    if(tempId.length > 0 && !tempId.startsWith("*")){
        dni.value = "";
    }
    else envioAutomatico(tempId.substring(1))
})

luego que la funcion envioautomatico reciba la cadena a enviar para modificar el valor que se envía con el formulario
function envioAutomatico(inputDni){
    if ( inputDni.length == 8 ) {
        dni = document.getElementById("dni");
        dni.value = inputDni;
        formulario.addEventListener("submit",enviarFormulario);
        formulario.submit();
   }
}

